# MT4 Expert Advisor EA issue with updating price for offline chart

Tags: mql4, mt4

The following script uses a timer and works well in normal charts to comment current candle closing price every 1 second on chart. However, on offline chart, it only loads the closing price once and does not update it every second. Here is the code:

```
void OnTimer()
  {
  int m=TimeSeconds(TimeLocal());


  double CloseValue = Close[0]; //Current Candle Close Value
  string CloseValueString = DoubleToString(CloseValue,5); //Current price 


  Comment(
  "Current value :",CloseValueString,"\n",
  "Candle time :",m
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the Refreshrates() function which updates data for the offline chart at the end of my function:

```
void OnTimer()
{
 int m=TimeSeconds(TimeLocal());


  double CloseValue = Close[0]; //Current Candle Close Value
  string CloseValueString = DoubleToString(CloseValue,5); //Current price 


  Comment(
  "Current value :",CloseValueString,"\n",
  "Candle time :",m
  );
RefreshRates();
}
```